# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 in Flask app

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm working on a Flask App using Virtualenv, Pandas and Python 3.7.

I made my main code (just do some Electrical calculation) using virtualenv and Python 3.7. and everything was working fine.

Then I create a simple Flask webapp with this code and I started getting some errors like:

1. AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')

for this line of code:

```
num_ac = df_quadro_cargas.index.str.contains('ar_condicionado').sum()
```

2. IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

for this line of code:

```
demanda = df[df.numero_aparelhos == num].fator_demanda.get_values()[0]
```

I did a workaround to the first one but since I did that, the second one occurred. I'm afraid I need to re-write a couple lines of code just for that.

My question is: Why the Flask app is given me another answer even it is using the environment?

Anybody faced that kind of error?

For the first error I changed the code as below:

```
name_tues = list(df_quadro_cargas.loc[df_quadro_cargas['tipo'] == 'tue'].index)
    # print(name_tues)
    num_ac = 0
    for tue in name_tues:
        if 'ar_condicionado' in tue:
            num_ac += 1
```

For the second error, looking the output for:

```
df[df.numero_aparelhos == num].fator_demanda.get_values()
```

I got the following array:

```
demanda = [1.]
```

Which seems correct to use [0] after get_values().

Any guess?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the variables are not passing through functions properly and because of that the strange behavior was detected.

1. First error, the dataframe was empty.
2. Second error, I just emphasize the type of the variable accepted by the function.

that's it.
Thank you! ;)